# Regular Expression - Specific range

Tags: regex

Can someone help me with a regex that validates if a string is in the range 249-268 and, if possible explain-me how it works every block of the regex?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't use a regex to solve this

Comment: @anubhava - That's not a recipe for generating regex for number ranges. It's a hyper simple view of the topic.

Comment: Use `>` and `<` or if in SQL `between`. If you updated the question with the language we could show you an efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the whole string you could use:

```
^2(49|5[0-9]|6[0-8])$
```

See demo: https://regex101.com/r/rJ2lH5/1

(If you don't want to match the whole string, you can remove the `^` and `$`.

Now, regex really don't know if this is a "range matching", it just matches the numbers we tell it to. In this specific case, the pattern is:

```
^          # assert position at start of a line
2          # matches the character 2 literally
1st Alternative: 49
  49       # matches the characters 49 literally
2nd Alternative: 5[0-9]
  5        # matches the character 5 literally
  [0-9]    # match a single character in the range between 0 and 9
3rd Alternative: 6[0-8]
  6        # matches the character 6 literally
  [0-8]    # match a single character in the range between 0 and 8
$          # assert position at end of a line
```